# How do I link an image in a svg file in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, svg

I'm trying to use a svg file that contains a vector and an image, the problem however is that the linked image in the svg won't load. The vector part of the svg is loading however. I figure the problem has to do with how wordpress loads its files. Both the image and the svg file are located in the image folder of my wordpress theme.
I've tried linking to the file by using the file path with `xlink:href="wp-content/themes/my-theme/assets/img/ulu-moskee.png"` and `xlink:href="wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme/assets/img/ulu-moskee.png"`. I've also tried linking to where the file is hosted with `xlink:href="www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/assets/img/ulu-moskee.png"` Despite these attempts, the image is still not loading. I'm seeking guidance on the correct path to use for xlink:href or any potential issues with how WordPress handles SVG images.
Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

INDEX.PHP:

`<div class="home"><img id="svg" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/ulu-home.svg' ); ?>" alt=""></div>`

SVG FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1569.79" height="870.31" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1569.79 870.31">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #4483e2;
      }

      .cls-1, .cls-2, .cls-3 {
        stroke-width: 0px;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: none;
      }

      .cls-3 {
        fill: #4783e3;
      }

      .cls-4 {
        clip-path: url(#clippath);
      }
    </style>
    <clipPath id="clippath">
      <path class="cls-2" d="m773.06,44.54c5.02,27.93,34.39,97.56,187.46,214.51,162.74,124.37,172.31,347.2,169.23,434.55,4.49,1.75,123.07,65,123.07,65h-479.75s-479.75,0-479.75,0c0,0,118.58-63.25,123.07-65-3.08-87.35,6.48-310.18,169.23-434.55,153.07-116.96,182.44-186.58,187.46-214.51Z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g class="cls-4">
    <image width="1920" height="1040" transform="translate(0 20.01) scale(.82)" xlink:href="ulu-moskee.png"/>
  </g>
  <path class="cls-3" d="m793.8,30.39c-3.24,8.28-11.31,14.15-20.74,14.15-12.3,0-22.27-9.97-22.27-22.27s9.97-22.27,22.27-22.27c1.28,0,2.54.11,3.76.32-8.43,1.6-14.81,9.01-14.81,17.9,0,10.07,8.16,18.23,18.22,18.23,5.39,0,10.24-2.34,13.57-6.06Z"/>
  <polygon class="cls-1" points="784.06 3.05 786.72 11.24 795.33 11.24 788.37 16.31 791.03 24.5 784.06 19.44 777.09 24.5 779.75 16.31 772.78 11.24 781.4 11.24 784.06 3.05"/>
</svg>
```